# Sending SMS via .NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sms

I was wondering what's the most convenient way to send an SMS through an a .NET application(more precisely - an ASP.NET MVC application). For example, someone makes a reservation for a restaurant and you want to inform them via text message that their reservation was successfully made with some info about it.

I came across a service called Twilo, which seemed to do the trick, but I later found out that in order for me to be able to send a message to a non-Twilo number, I had to add that number to a list called "**Verified Caller IDs**" and then the owner of that number then would receive a verification number with which to verify this as a valid number. So that was a let down. Maybe if I upgrade my account, that won't be needed but I'm not sure.

This is the code template I'm executing to test how the service works:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account

        string AccountSid = "<AccountSid>";
        string AuthToken = "<AuthToken>";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var message = twilio.SendMessage("<FromNumber>", "<ToNumber>", "<BodyText>");
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
    }
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: this is basically offtopic for SO, but you might want to look at clickatell

Comment: We use Twilio - that's not the case. You can reserve a normal looking (long code) phone number with Twilio and use it to text any valid mobile number as you're looking to do.  Those "Verified Caller IDs" are for porting numbers from other carriers, hosting existing landlines and other services like that.

Comment: I tried to send an SMS to a number which was not in that list and nothing happened. Only after adding it, was the issue resolved. Could that be because I'm using the service with a trial account?

Comment: Yes thats a limitation with trial account . If you upgrade your account and put some credit (5$ should be good) , you should be able to send SMS to any(well mostly , depending on country and provider rules)  number